# Display groups with different borders in histogram with panel.superpose

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663875/how-to-add-overlapping-histograms-with-lattice/28326084#28326084) shows how to use `groups` and `panel.superpose` to display overlapping histograms in the same panel, assigning different colors to each histogram.  In addition, I want to give each histogram a different border color.  (This will allow me to display one histogram as solid bars without a border, overlayed with a transparent, all-border histogram.  The example below is a little different for the sake of clarity.)

Although it's possible to use `border=` to use different border colors in the plot, they are not assigned to groups as fill colors are with `col=`. If you give `border=` a sequence of colors, it seems to cycle through them one bar at at time.  If the two histograms overlap, the effect is a bit silly (see below).

Is there a way to give each group a specific border color?

```
# This illustrates the problem: Assignment of border colors to bars ignores grouping:

# make some data
foo.df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)+2), cat=c(rep("A", 10),rep("B", 10)))

# plot it
histogram(~ x, groups=cat, data=foo.df, ylim=c(0,75), breaks=seq(-3, 5, 0.5), lwd=2,
          panel=function(...)panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=panel.histogram, 
                                             col=c("transparent", "cyan"), 
                                             border=c(rep("black", 3), rep("red", 3))))
```

Note that you can't just count how many bars there are in each group and provide those numbers to `rep` in the `border` setting.  If the two histograms overlap, at least one of the histograms will use two border colors.

[image: overlapping histograms showing cycling border colors]

(It's the `panel.superpose` code that places the groups on the same panel and that assigns the colors.  I don't have a deep understanding of it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`panel.histogram()` doesn't have a formal `groups=` argument, and if you examine its code, you'll see that it handles any supplied `groups=` argument differently and in a less standard way than `panel.*()` functions that do. The upshot of that design decision is that (as you've found) it's not in general easy to pass in to it vectors of graphical parameters specifying per-group appearance

As a workaround, I'd suggest using **latticeExtra**'s `+()` and `as.layer()` functions  to overlay a number of separate `histogram()` plots, one for each group. Here's how you might do that:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

## Split your data by group into separate data.frames
foo.df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)+2), cat=c(rep("A", 10),rep("B", 10)))
foo.A <- subset(foo.df, cat=="A")
foo.B <- subset(foo.df, cat=="B")

## Use calls to `+ as.layer()` to layer each group's histogram onto previous ones  
histogram(~ x, data=foo.A, ylim=c(0,75), breaks=seq(-3, 5, 0.5), 
          lwd=2, col="transparent", border="black") +
as.layer(
histogram(~ x, data=foo.B, ylim=c(0,75), breaks=seq(-3, 5, 0.5), 
          lwd=2, col="cyan", border="red") 
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Cool--I'll try this.  In the first line of the answer, you mean `panel.histogram`, right?  (It's unfortunate that breaks have to be handled manually.  Another solution I found has the same drawback.  That's not a big problem, but one of the points of Lattice is to do that for you.  I think that Sarkar probably felt that groups in histograms were a bad idea, which they are, usually, but it's clear that there are a few cases in which that's not so.)

Comment: @Mars Thanks for catching that typo. And yeah, I agree that Sarkar probably didn't include support for groups in histograms because there's so little legitimate need for it!