# Histogram in R with groups using Lattice/Mosaic?

Tags: r, histogram, visualization, lattice, r-mosaic

I am trying to make a histogram with two groups: one where (x<60 || x>100), and one where that condition is false.

Basically like this: [image: histogram with vertical bars and colored groups]

### update 2023.08.03 - - - - - - -

This code is exactly what I want, but the color seems to be leaking between the lines:

```
histogram(~pulse, data = data, v = c(60,100), breaks = c(seq(from=40,to=140,by=20)), type = "percent", groups = ((pulse >= 100) | (pulse <= 60)))
```

[histogram with vertical lines at 60 and 100, orange outside the lines and blue inside with some orange in the blue bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bukwk.png) <kbd>image</kbd>

I tried:

- restarting R
- [only one line/break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1nTC.png)  <kbd>image</kbd>:

```
histogram(~pulse, data = data, v = 100,
    breaks = c(seq(from=40,to=140,by=20)),
    type = "percent", groups = (pulse >= 100))
```

- [naming the constant where I want the line/group split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygaII.png)  <kbd>image</kbd>:

```
histogram(~pulse, data = data, v = num,
    breaks = c(40,60,80,num,120,140),
    type = "percent", groups = (pulse >= 100))
```

- [different bin widths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfxCs.png)  <kbd>image</kbd>:

```
histogram(~pulse, data = data, v = 100,
    breaks = c(seq(from=40,to=140,by=10)),
    type = "percent", groups = (pulse >= 100))
```

- [not specifying the breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uafcD.png)  <kbd>image</kbd>:

```
histogram(~pulse, data = data, v = 100,
    type = "percent", groups = (pulse >= 100))
```

If you have any ideas please let me know! I'm really hoping to stick to Lattice since I already have quite a few of these typed out ':)

### end of update - - - - - - -

I tried this code but it gives me an error:

```
histogram(~pulse, data=data, type="percent", breaks=10, labels = TRUE, groups = (pulse > 60))
```

- Error using packet 1
- 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0

This code works, but it is only half of what I want:

```
set.seed(123)
var <- rnorm(700, 0, 0.25)
df <- as.data.frame(var)
num <- 0.5
histogram(~var, data = df, v = num, width = 0.2, type = "percent", groups = (var >= num))
```

My output: [histogram with vertical line that splits it into blue and orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEiJV.png) <kbd>image</kbd>

I have vague ideas of messing with `panel` or `panel.superpose` or maybe `allow.multiple`?

If this is relevant, here is my session info and more on the first histogram:

> R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- "Already Tomorrow"
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

[histogram variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbNUT.png) <kbd>image</kbd>

Comment: I think you might be committing a logical error. The expression `(x>60 || x<100),` is going to be true for every numeric value. Perhaps you want `&`? I'm also guess ing that you have not provided an accurate recounting of the error message: It's hard to believe it really said "'x' and 'units' must have length < 0"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! So, is it that you want one histogram showing the tails of the distribution, and one showing the center? @IRTFM is correct in saying that your logical statement `(x>60 || X<100)` is true for all values, but if you want the tails and the center on separate plots, I'm sure we can help.

Comment: Hi Isabelle, welcome to StackOverflow! Re: the code below where you said "This code works, but it is only half of what I want:", doesn't actually change colour for me ...? It does produce a histogram, but one with only one colour, blue

Comment: @Mark I added an image of what the working histogram looks like for me

Comment: @IRTFM I fixed the signs for both the expression and the error message (I just had them backwards)

Comment: @ReedMerrill do they need to be on separate plots? I definitely want it to look like just one histogram, but I am not that familiar with lattice

Comment: @isabelle-smith ah, putting it all on a single plot actually makes more sense and is probably easier to do. I think this would be easier using `ggplot`. I'll write an answer tonight.

Comment: Seems to me that this answer probably has all the code to do this in the Lattice system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850491/how-to-superimpose-a-histogram-on-each-panel/33904407#33904407. Basically you just need to create one variable that holds the class of the outliers and only plot one panel.

Comment: @IRTFM making two separate histograms does not work when the graph is in percent/proportions (P.S. if you are still interested I updated the post after some more messing around)